# Laravel Eloquent add the withCount method

Tags: laravel

There are methods in controller which get all published posts sorted by published_at and show one post

```
public function show($id) {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        session()->reflash();
        return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'random'));
    }

public function index() {
        $posts = Post::latest('published_at')->published()->paginate(10);
        return view('home.index', compact('posts'));
    }
```

also every post has likes, so I need to get posts with likes and post with likes.
So I need to use something like that (That is example from documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

```
$posts = App\Post::withCount('likes')->get();
```

How could I add `withCount()` method to my methods?

Comment: Why can't you just do `$posts = Post::latest('published_at')->published()->withCount('likes')->paginate(10);` and `$post = Post::withCount('likes')->findOrFail($id);`

Comment: I've tried `$posts = Post::latest('published_at')->published()->withCount('likes'‌​)->paginate(10);` but error FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 15:
syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING)

Comment: @Heidel where did you find **`published`** method?

Comment: It's `scope` from Post model `public function scopePublished($query) 
    {
        $query->where('is_published', 1);
    }`